# Using the BigQuery sandbox, how to check free Quota usage?

Tags: google-bigquery

I started using the new free BigQuery sandbox, I know the limitation is 1TB/Month, but how I check, how much I used already, my project has no billing.

thanks

it is a bug in the system, Quota usage don't show if you don't enable billing

["Exceeded quota: too many free query bytes scanned for this project" in Google BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122202/exceeded-quota-too-many-free-query-bytes-scanned-for-this-project-in-google-b?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still can use cloud console to reach Quotas details

https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?project=your_project

Comment: does it keep showing 0, or does it just take some time to catch up? can you confirm it's for the same project?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa himself, what a honor !!, yes it is the same project, actually, I have only one project, always 0

Comment: Thanks! I can report that in my billed project my quota page reflects usage a couple minutes later, but in my billing-less project it doesn't. So that seems like a bug.