# Loading BQ data to power BI

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi

While pushing BQ data to power BI it throwed an error

```
Processing error: ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][BigQuery] (100) Error interacting with REST API: Quota exceeded: Your project exceeded quota for free query bytes scanned. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors
Cluster URI: xxxxxxxx
Activity ID: 21ad96b0-e49c-47da-b715-7444d2f5c821
Request ID: 7c30f314-92d5-1e0c-f1e7-08e23a443582
Time: 2021-08-09 01:59:59Z
```

stating quota exceded  But my account is a billing account so is there any way to fix this error

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your Power BI query is not associated with your billing account, so it doesn't know that you are a paying customer rather than on the free usage tier.

As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68679946/765226) and [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Quota-exceeded-Your-project-exceeded-quota-for-free-query-bytes/m-p/1707982), the key is to include your project ID in your query connection.

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-connect-bigquery#considerations-and-limitations) clarifies that you should include it using this syntax within your M query:

```
Source = GoogleBigQuery.Database([BillingProject="Include-Billing-Project-Id-Here"])
```